# Setting ANSI mode in MariaDB Docker Image

Tags: docker, mariadb, ansi

I am running MariaDB in a Docker image on my Macintosh.

I want to set MariaDB to ANSI mode. I know I can set it during a session with:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

but I would prefer to set it permanently. On my Linux server, I set it in the `my.cnf` file, which does the job nicely, but I can’t see how to access this inside the docker image.

How can I set MariaDB to Ansi mode permanently?

Comment: Do it in the config file.  Look for `my.cnf`.

Comment: @RickJames Where would I find that in the docker image?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/ - There is a section (scroll down) that talks about setting up a configuration file that augments the default file.